# Why doesn't this telnet command connect to this socket "server IP and SMTP port" in command line

Tags: cmd, smtp, telnet

```
C:\Users\Kyle>telnet 10.0.0.1 25
```

The response that I get is:

```
Connecting To 10.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed
```

Comment: Is there a routing problem, a firewall blocking port 25, a telnetd running on that hostname listening on that port?

Comment: @mao I googled 'what is telnet' and it says that it is a way of connecting devices on the same network. Does that mean that I can't connect to a external server IP?

Comment: @mao the hostname needs to be running telnet?

Comment: You Can access  hosts not on your network if nothing is blocking the path and port.  Target host must run a telnet server.

Answer (score 0):

Some ISP will block port 25 due to spamming concern. Consider to try with port 587 instead.

Answer (score 0):

10.0.0.1 is a private IP address.  You can only connect directly to that IP address if there is a server at that address on your local network.  You should verify that there is a server at that IP address, and that the server is running a program that is listening for connections on port 25.